# How to place resolvectl commands in ovpn profile?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, openvpn

I've got an ovpn config to connect to private network from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. But every time after starting the vpn I have to run those commands

```
resolvectl dns tun0 10.0.0.255
resolvectl domain tun0 "~domain1.com"
resolvectl domain tun0 "~domain2.com"
```

to make dns work with private subdomains. Is it possible to include those commands into ovpn config and execute them automatically, when I connect to this vpn?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using network-manager-openvpn like me, this could help to resolve the issue persistently:

```
sudo nmcli connection modify VPN_NAME \                              
    ipv4.dns-search '~domain1.com, ~domain2.com' ipv6.dns-search '~domain1.com, ~domain2.com' ipv4.dns 10.0.0.255
```

Source: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/systemd-resolved-not-querying-dns-server-set-by-openvpn/9696/9

I didn't try the part regarding the dns server.
Be careful. This overwrites pushed settings. If you want to use some of the domains as search domains, simply omit the '~'.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `--up` and `--down` parameters (or `up` / `down` configuration directives) to point to a script, which will be run after establishing / closing connection. You may **not** use shell expressions (like `--up 'resolvectl dns tun0 10.0.0.255 && resolvectl domain tun0 "~domain1.com"'`) - it won't work.

Also, to allow OpenVPN calling external scripts, please pass `--script-security 2`.

Please read the [official OpenVPN documentation](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/) shall you have more questions.